# Zend_Db -> update() increments my values twice

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Here is my code:

```
$update_data = array('post_browe_count'=>new Zend_Db_Expr('post_browe_count+1'));

$rowaffected = $contentmodel->update_post('posts',$update_data,$id);
```

my class extend directly from Zend_Db_Table_Abstract,how can I solve it

Comment: it looks like the query runs twice. I would enable firebug profiler to see what's going on. [enable firebug profiler](http://aaronsaray.com/blog/2011/06/17/useful-firebug-tricks-with-zend-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

Here i am giving you an example using products and incrementing a quantity field:

```
$table     = 'products'; 
$data      = array('prd_qnty' => new Zend_Db_Expr('product_qnty + 1')); 
$where[] = $db->quoteInto('product_id = ?', $this->pr_id); 
$db->update($table, $data, $where);
```

just try to do your query as above. so it will sure work for you.

let me know if i can help you more.